# Running single integration test inside docker in maven

Tags: java, maven, docker, integration-testing, presto

I am trying to run integration testing on my maven project inside a docker container. I am using [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) plugin to move jar file inside my docker container and maven-failsafe-plugin to initiate my integration testing. But somehow integration testing starts before docker being built. Also it doesn't call my test functions.

Here is my pom.xml snippet.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                        <goal>push</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <repository>rohitbarnwal7/presto_him</repository>
                <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                <buildArgs>
                    <JAR_FILE>plugin-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Update: With above configuration, integration test class are being called but none of the test is actually executed.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide maven configuration for docker maven plugin?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the building of the image to a maven phase that runs before integration test.

As documented in [Bind Docker commands to Maven phases](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#bind-docker-commands-to-maven-phases), you can bind building the docker image to a specific maven phase as such:

build-image
      compile
      
        package

In this case, building the image will take place at the maven `package` phase which will run before `integration-test` phase

Comment: Can there be any goal which start/run the docker image? Basically how can I perform test if I need to connect with server running inside a docker for integration testing.

Comment: With my updated pom.xml IntegrationTest class is being called, but none of the test is running.
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Any help with this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639730/maven-not-running-integration-test-methods